# How to add BOM to file using C

Tags: c, utf-8, file-handling, byte-order-mark

how can i add Byte order mark (BOM) to output file using C?

my output file is ANSI as UTF-8 (which mean UTF-8 without BOM)

but i need it to be UTF-8 with BOM

how can i do that?

Comment: Write the BOM before the UTF-8 data. (It's literally two additional bytes).

Comment: @Whoz Well, it's three

Comment: @user Perhaps you can tell us what you are finding hard. Do you know how to write to a file? Have you tried to write the BOM?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're totally right. I was spacing out and thinking of the 2-byte BOM for UTF-16, not the 3-byte BOM `0xef 0xbb 0xbf` for UTF-8.

Comment: There is no ANSI as UTF-8. ANSI is an institute, UTF-8 a char encoding.

Comment: @Michael-O - Sometimes [Extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) is referred to as [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_art), but I have a feeling he meant ASCII

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur: that may sound logical but in fact ASCII and UTF8 mutually exclusive :-) Even though the ASCII set is a subset of UTF8, if you say you have "ASCII" output, it *automatically* prohibits UTF8 sequences. "ASCII (or "ANSI") with UTF8" is, like, C with classes.

Comment: It should be noted that using a BOM on an UTF8 file is overkill (or perhaps "well-intended misuse"). The purpose of the BOM is to indicate byte order in 16-and-more bit Unicode files. UTF8 files do not suffer from byte order issues (...) but *do* suffer from "how do I recognize the encoding as UTF8". (According to http://www.utf-8.com/ it's the default encoding for XML; other files may have their encoding in a DOCTYPE definition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the answer is

```
printf("\xef\xbb\xbf");
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan are these characters supposed to be visible in notepad++ ?